# FirstOrDefault returns Null even if there's a value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

As you see there's a clear match in the List I have given below. However, firstordefault returns a Null. How can I solve this ?

I have 2 List objects. OldAnimals and latestAnimals. I need to find a match of the oldAnimal in the latestAnimal list.

My code is as follows:

```
oldAnimal = [{"iden":1 , "gen": "aaa"},{"iden":2 , "gen": "bbb"},{"iden":3 , "gen": "ccc"},{"iden":4 , "gen": "aaxde"}]

latestAnimal= [{"iden":1 , "gen": "xxx"},{"iden":2 , "gen": "xddfddse"},{"iden":3 , "gen": "ccc"},{"iden":4 , "gen": "aaxde"}]

Animal ani= latestAnimal.FirstOrDefault(a=> a.iden == oldAnimal.iden &&
                            a.gen== oldAnimal.gen
                            );
```

Comment: Moreover, just explain what you actually wanting, rather than just showing your code?

Comment: is this C# code, can we defined variable like oldAnimal ?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram `oldAnimal` is an array then how he can write `oldAnimal.iden`?

Comment: @TanvirArjel, I agree, I misread it initially. As presented, his third statement makes little sense.

Comment: I have edited the code. I have taken off the Animal part if it. it was a copy-paste error.

Comment: @Illep Now explain what you actually wanting from these two array?

Comment: I have updated my post. Its just a simple query, I need to find a match of the oldAnimal record in the latestAnimal list that we have

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be as follows:

```
 var animals = latestAnimal.Where(l => oldAnimal.All(o => o.iden == a.iden && o.gen == a.gen)).ToArray();
```

Comment: They might want to use .Any rather than .All

Answer (score 0):

It's not doing what you want because you're only iterating over one of the arrays. You want to iterate over both in some way.

The code you wrote checks whether `latestAnimal[0].iden == oldAnimal.iden`, then it checks whether `latestAnimal[1].iden == oldAnimal.iden`, etc

I assume you actually want to have it start by checking whether `latestAnimal[0].iden == oldAnimal[0].iden`

From the code you've posted I can't tell whether you want to compare `latestAnimal[0]` with `oldAnimal[1]` or not. If you don't, I suggest a for loop. If you do, it can be done with either nested for loops, or `latestAnimal.FirstOrDefault(a=> oldAnimal.Any(b =>` etc